# Why do i get a linker error,when everything is in one file?

Tags: c++, templates

I get a LNK 2019 error in VS.

I have read a couple of similiar problems,but could not understand what i should do.As much as i understood VS can't find  the template class code for some reason.I am not sure.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

template<typename T>
struct item {
    item* pointer = nullptr;
    T value;
};
template <typename T>
class stack {
private:
    item<T>* top;
public:
    stack() { top = nullptr; };
    ~stack();
    void push(const T& s) {
        item<T>* p = top;
        top = new item<T>;
        assert(top != nullptr);
        top->value = s;
        top->pointer = p;
        std::cout << "The item has been pushed." << std::endl;
    }
    void pop() {
        T s;
        if (!top) {
            std::cout << "The stack is empty." << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            s = top->value;
            item<T>* p = top;
            top = top->pointer;
            delete p;
            std::cout << "The item has been  popped." << std::endl;
        }
    };
    void check() {
        if (!top) { std::cout << "The stack is empty." << std::endl; }
        else { std::cout << "It has elements in it." << std::endl; }
    }
};
int main()
{
    stack<int> test;
    return 0;
}
```

I want afterwards to be able to push and pop elements.So that i can continue on with my project.

Comment: You need to define `stack::~stack()`.

Comment: A good question would include the linker error text.

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared a destructor for `stack` here:

```
~stack();
```

but you don't define it. Change the above to

```
~stack() { /* Clean up resources here. */ }
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, if you declare a destructor, you have to define it. Even if the destructor is pure virtual, you still have to define it or else you'll get linker error, as is the case here. If you are fine with the default destructor, but still want to declare it for some reason, for instance, to make it virtual, you can use the keyword `default`:

```
virtual ~stack() = default;
```

You can learn more about the `default` keyword [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/default).